# Brightness filters & battery

Tags: display, battery, brightness

I have various screen filters on either pc or mobile that artificially lower brightness. I don't know if it just covers whole screen with semitransparent black layer("dimmer") or really adjustes the brightness(most likely the first option).

The thing is: Will the screen drain my battery less even if it's only a black layer on the screen, or will there be a real effect only if the hardware brightness settings are adjusted?

Comment: It depends on the type of the display, back-lit (LCD) vs active emitters (OLED).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well, (AM)OLED on mobiles and LCD with IPS on pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filters actually adjusts the hardware brightness it does not really matter.

If the filters are just making everything on the screen "more black" by putting a semi-transparent overlay of black over everything then it would depend on the technology the display uses.

Back-lit displays  that use a single light source like older LCDs get their hardware level brightness from a light source behind the LCD cells. If that light source has a adjustable intensity and that is how the screen handles brightness then a "true" lower brightness would draw less power but a "fake" lower brightness from a overlay would still draw the full power amount.

Display technologies that have cells that produce their own light like OLED or CRTs will make the cell produce less light to produce darker colors. So in that case having more black on screen will cause it to draw less power.